# unhandled exception sometimes when calling fcout

Tags: c++

I have this function to write some log information to a file

```
int Comm::saveInfo(LPTSTR msg)
{
#ifdef _log
    wofstream fcout(LogFile, ios::out | ios::app);
     if (fcout.is_open())
     {

        fcout << msg << "\t" << (int) ::GetTickCount64() << endl;
        fcout.close();
     }
#endif
    return 0; // this is where visual studio 2012 is pointing to for the crash
}
```

This function works sometimes but sometimes crashes... :(

Here is how I call this function:

```
saveInfo(TEXT("set measurement time..."));
ret = readMsg(Buf, WAITTIMOUT);
```

In the header file of `Comm` class I declare `std::wstring LogFile;` as private member. `readMsg` is a function to read the pipe

```
int CpipeComm::readMsg(LPTSTR chBuf, DWORD timeout)
{

    OVERLAPPED overlapped;
    memset(&overlapped, 0, sizeof(overlapped));
    memset(&chBuf[0], 0, sizeof(chBuf));

    int err = 0; 
    ULONGLONG time1 = ::GetTickCount64();
    DWORD bytesRead = 0;
    do 
    { 
   // Read from the pipe. 
      fSuccess = ReadFile( 
         hPipe,    // pipe handle 
         chBuf,    // buffer to receive reply 
         BUFSIZE*sizeof(TCHAR),  // size of buffer 
         &cbRead,  // number of bytes read 
         &overlapped);    // not overlapped 

return 0;
}
```

And in  the constructor of Comm class I do

```
 LogFile.assign(L"Pipe_log.log");
```

The random error that I am getting is;

```
Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEF782AFD3 (msvcp110.dll) in : 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000012.
```

I am not sure if there is anything that I am doing wrong! Somehow having these two functions one after another is causing the crash! If I moved `saveInfo` function to another place things work fine...

Comment: It looks like you might be dereferencing a null pointer. Unfortunately, there isn't enough here to really diagnose the issue.

Comment: Sounds like you're accessing out-of-bounds memory... Run your program in a debugger until the error occurs; the debugger should catch it and report where it happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no valid file stream constructor that takes a `std::wstring` as the file name.  It looks like that is the type of `LogFile`, based on your example for initialising it.

You should instead construct the stream like this:

```
wofstream fcout( LogFile.c_str(), ios::out | ios::app );
```